# elasticsearch weekly date histogram how dates are determined

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running a weekly date histogram aggregation, over an index that contains a field `samplingDate` and a field `users`. This is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
     "samplingDate": {
       "gte": "2016-08-14",
       "lte": "2016-09-12"
     }
   }
 },
 "aggs": {
   "dateagg": {
     "date_histogram": {
       "field": "samplingDate",
       "interval": "week"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "totalusers": {
          "max": {
           "field": "users"
         }
      }
    }
   }
 }  
}
```

The bucket returns a set of results, where the first date is 2016-08-08 (out of range, why?) and subsequent dates are 7 days apart. My question is, how does elasticsearch determine which dates to display on a weekly aggregation, and what do I have to do so that the last item in bucket will have the date of the upper bound (2016-09-12 in this case). Elasticsearch version is 2.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2016-08-14 was a Sunday and the `date_histogram` bucket aggregation with a `week` interval computes bounds based on "start of week" (i.e. Monday), so that's why the first bucket is 2016-08-08.

However, you can add a `top_hits` sub-aggregation in your date histogram buckets, and you'll see that you only have documents from 2016-08-14 onwards (i.e. based on your query).

Comment: so each date in a bucket will always be a Monday, and if I want to shift it I can use the offset key?

Answer (score 0):

if week interval is given it starts from 'monday' for each date in the histogram results.